Can a Faraday Disc Charge a Capacitor?
As I understand it, a Faraday disc requires a load between its output terminals in order for its radial E field to be maintained. Does a capacitor alone count as a load in this context, or does the load need to be through resistance with actual current flowing?
In short, if two terminals of a Faraday disc are connected only to a capacitor, will the capacitor charge?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I do not think that As I understand it, a Faraday disc requires a load between its output terminals in order for its radial E field to be maintained. is correct. A motional emf does not require an induced current to flow.

Don't the potentials within the disc cancel themselves out when unconnected?

Regardless, is the answer to my question yes? A capacitor alone will charge?

The answer is no, why did you think there should be a difference with other generators?

Why would other generators not be able to charge a capacitor?
